# How to get itemvalue from selectonemenu JSF

Tags: java, jsf

i need to get itemValue from `<f:selectedItems>`

this is my xhtml

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5"> 
    <p:outputLabel for="negara" value="Negara"></p:outputLabel>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="negara" value="#{propinsiBacking.countryID}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{propinsiBacking.listNegara}" var="negara" itemLabel="#{negara.countryName}" itemValue="#{negara.countryID}"></f:selectItems>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton value="Go" action="#{propinsiBacking.test}"></p:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

and my backingBean
this is i get data from database

```
private List<NegaraEntity> listNegara;
private int countryID;
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    listNegara = negaraRules.getNegara();
}
```

and i want to get id from `<f:selectedItem>` so i `sytem.out.println` like this

```
public void test(int ctyId)
{
    ctyId = countryID;
    System.out.println(ctyId);
}
```

but this not working,any idea?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the method `public void test(int ctyId)` because it have a param `int ctyid`

JSF must say: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException

Change to `public void test()` remember that apply request values phase occurs before invoke application phase, so `#{propinsiBacking.countryID}` is already set when method is executed.

Answer (score 0):

change public void test
be

```
public String test()
{
    System.out.println(countryID);
    return "null";
}
```